# Create a brand new custom membership provider and authenticate from that

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

I have to develop a brand new custom membership provider(MyCustomProvider) in which i have to implement all the methods like validate user, CreateUser and all other and use this membership provider as authentication mechanism for my sharepoint site. I have implemented it completely. Now i am left with using it for authentication. I want to know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

After implementing your Provider you just set it up in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyCustomProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyCustomProvider" type="My.Namespace.MyCustomProvider" connectionStringName="myConnStr"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="MyApp" />
      </providers>
    </membership>      
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then you can use [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx), [Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) and all the other cool features.

Also check out this [MSDN example for custom Membership Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read - [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)